# QML and Qt : issues

Tags: qt, qml

I want my window elements take the same height and width as the application window

I want like when i click on one of the button , it displays on the rectangle , Could you please explain me how to do it because i searched but i didn't really understand

edit: i modify my code as many of you suggested but the probleme when i try marginleft property for the footer , nothing happened and my buttons aren't showing up , here is my code

```
import QtQuick 2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts



ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    property string displayedButton: ""
    width: 800
        height: 380
    visible: true

    Page {
        anchors.fill: parent

        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent

            ListView {
                id: leftMenuBar
                Layout.preferredWidth: 90
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                clip: true
                spacing: 10
                model: 3
                delegate: Button {
                    text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                    onClicked: displayedButton = text
                    width: 90
                    height: 90
                }

                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
                Layout.leftMargin: 20
            }

            Item {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 20
                    border.width: 2
                    border.color: "lightgray"
                    radius: 35

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "Selected Button: " + displayedButton
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        footer: RowLayout{


            ListView {
                id: bottomMenuBar
                implicitHeight: 90
                clip:true

                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                spacing: 10

                Layout.preferredWidth:90



                Layout.leftMargin:20


                Repeater {
                       model: 8
                       delegate: Button {
                           text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                           onClicked: displayedButton = text
                           width: 90
                           height: 90
                       }
                   }


            }
        }


    }
}
```

And what i noticed when i made some modification , while i double click my window , button are displayed with random spacing , it that because i should use implicit height and width for them?

[when i double click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxBe8.png)

**i know i have not upload images but it's just for more clarification

Comment: Row and Column take their size (width _or_ height, respectively) from their contents. To control content size, use RowLayout and ColumnLayout.

Comment: Why `Layout.preferredWidth:90` in your footerMenuBar? Makes no sense, perhaps `Layout.fillWidth: true` has more meaning here. Alternatively, `Layout.preferredHeight: 90` is an appropriate replacement for `implicitHeight: 90`.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to consider:

- Be carefull about the MouseArea: 2 MouseArea shouldn't take care of same area in the space. In your example this happens and causes the buttons are not working
- You don't need to define a property inside rectangle, you can assign the Text by simply giving it an id. `displayedText.text = "Selected Button: " + text`

Here is the modified version of your code which you need:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow
{

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 380
    title: "Menu Example"

    Column {
        id: leftMenuBar
        width: 100
        height: parent.height
        spacing: 10
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        Repeater {
            model: 3

            Button {
                text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                onClicked: displayedText.text = "Selected Button: " + text

                width: 80
                height: 80
            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        id: bottomMenuBar
        width: parent.width
        height: 80
        spacing: 10
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 2

        Repeater {
            model: 8

            Button {
                text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                onClicked: displayedText.text = "Selected Button: " + text
                width: 80
                height:80
                anchors.bottomMargin: 5
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 530
        height: 280
        anchors.left: leftMenuBar.right
        anchors.leftMargin : 2
        anchors.topMargin: bottomMenuBar.height

        anchors.rightMargin: 5

        y:7
        anchors.margins: -9

        border.width: 2
        border.color: "lightgray"
        radius: 35

        Text {
            id: displayedText
            font.pixelSize: 20
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first change I would make is to move the definition of your `displayedButton` to the root level of your app. That way, every component within, can read/write that property without needing to define scope. Property binding means when any `Button` updates the value of `displayedButton` it will automatically get shown in the `Text` below.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    property string displayedButton: ""
    //...
    Button {
        text: "Button " + (index + 1)
        onClicked: displayedButton = text
    }
    //...
    Text {
        //id: displayedText // no need for an id here
        text: "Selected Button: " + displayedButton
        font.pixelSize: 20
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

As to sizing and placing of the `Button`, `Rectangle` there are many improvements you can consider such as `RowLayout`, `ColumnLayout` as mentioned in the comments. The layout controls allow us to allocate space to our controls without the need to specify anchoring. You make use of `Layout` attached properties such as `Layout.fillWidth: true`, `Layout.fillHeight: true`, `Layout.orientation: Qt.AlignTop` and so forth.

I would also consider using `Page` which has a built-in `footer` component so no need to define anchoring or layouts to separate the footerMenuBar as you get that for free.

Instead of `Column+Repeater`, `Row+Repeater` for displaying your buttons, I would consider using `ListView` which combines the two. Another feature the `ListView` implements is a flickable action so, if the window is shrunk you can scroll the `ListView` menu bar to see any buttons that were off-screen.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    property string displayedButton: ""
    Page {
        anchors.fill: parent
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ListView {
                id: leftMenuBar
                Layout.preferredWidth: 90
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                clip: true
                spacing: 10
                model: 3
                delegate: Button {
                    text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                    onClicked: displayedButton = text
                    width: 90
                    height: 90
                }
            }
            Item {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 20
                    border.width: 2
                    border.color: "lightgray"
                    radius: 35
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "Selected Button: " + displayedButton
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        footer: ListView {
            id: bottomMenuBar
            implicitHeight: 90
            clip: true
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            spacing: 10
            model: 8
            delegate: Button {
                text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                onClicked: displayedButton = text
                width: 90
                height: 90
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: with footer property i could not have layout.leftMargin? because when i try to add this kind of property it does not work with me

Comment: Of course you can: `footer: RowLayout { ListView { Layout.leftMargin: 40 } }`. You still have the advantage over anchoring since, as I indicated, footer provides an built in sepration between your bottomMenuBar and your body and it's automatically expands to fill the width.